# Filtering by linked table and multiple parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have the following structure:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, DateTime, Table, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

mods_dependencies = Table('unity_mods_dependencies', base.metadata,
    Column('mod_id', Integer, ForeignKey('mods.id')),
    Column('dependence', Integer, ForeignKey('mods.id')),
    extend_existing=True
)

class Mod(base):
    __tablename__ = 'mods'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    dependencies = relationship('Mod', secondary=mods_dependencies, primaryjoin=(mods_dependencies.c.mod_id == id),
        secondaryjoin=(mods_dependencies.c.dependence == id), backref='mods',
        foreign_keys=[mods_dependencies.c.mod_id, mods_dependencies.c.dependence]
    )
```

I need to filter out mods because they have other mods in their dependencies. I can filter by one of the dependencies, but if I pass more than 1 element I get an empty list:

```py
from sqlalchemy import delete, insert, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import sql_data_client as sdc #my library, see the code above

if len(data.get("dependencies", [])) > 0:
    query = query.join(sdc.mods_dependencies, sdc.Mod.id == sdc.mods_dependencies.c.mod_id)
    for currect_dependence in data["dependencies"]:
        query = query.filter(sdc.mods_dependencies.c.dependence == currect_dependence)
mods = query.all()
```

When I pass a list of mod ids I want to get a list of mods whose dependencies have all the mods I passed (but not limited to that).